# How to retrieve the password with emailaddress using wcf rest service with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, android, wcf, rest, cordova

In my phonegap android application I want to retrieve the password using email address from the database in the server.I have called the wcf Rest service using JQuery Ajax.

Here My Iservice

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "RetrivalPassWord/EmailAddress={EmailAddress}", Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string RetrivalPassWord(string EmailAddress);
```

Here is my wcf service used to retrieve password using email address(Both are located in MS-Sql database ).My problem is when I set the breakpoint in the `service1.svc` I am able to retrieve the password,but unable to display that password in JQuery.

#### Service1.Svc:

```
public string RetrivalPassWord(string EmailAddress)
    {

        Debugger.Break();
        try
        {
            DataTable dtTable = new DataTable("Report");

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spRetivalOf_PassWord]", connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", EmailAddress));

                        adapter.Fill(dtTable);
                        connection.Close();
                        string data1 = dtTable.Rows[0]["credentials"].ToString();
                        return data1;



                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clsLog objLog = new clsLog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Log\\log.txt", 0);
            objLog.Write(ex.ToString());
            //return -1;
            //return "error";
            //DataTable dt = new DataTable("Error");
            //return dt;
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

#### My JQuery Ajax

```
function RetrivalPassword() {
 $("#btn").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",


                url: " http://localhost:49914/Service1.svc/RetrivalPassWord/EmailAddress=@EmailAddress",

                data: '{ "EmailAddress": "' + $("#email").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",

                success: function (data1) {

                    var result = eval(data1);
                    for (var property in result) {

                        alert(result[property]);
                    }


                },

                Error: function (e) { alert(e.statusText); }
            });
        });
    }
```

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is a good idea to build a service which lets you retrieve a password for a given user. This has severe security implications.

What exactly are you trying to build? (there should be a better way of solving this, rather than retrieving passwords by service..., OAuth, letting your server handle authentification without the password beeing sent over the wire...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I dont consider about the security.I want to just retrieve the password.Kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance.